# Android Studio giving warning while running on virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio

While running android studio on a virtual device I am getting this warning:-"You do not have permissions to run the application on this device".What should be the changes in AndroidManifest.xml ?As I have heard that you need to add permission manually if you are using Marshmallow.

Comment: Add you build.gradle .

Comment: Post build.gradle code and device configuration

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
   }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
           url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 25
                buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}